# Javascript Result of expression is not an object

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Using this to get rid of an annoying tiny little 'powered by' box, but it keeps saying
'TypeError: Result of expression 'divs[i]' [undefined] is not an object.'
How do I fix it.

```
function damnwhitebox()
{
 var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
 divs = myBody.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var i in divs)
    {
        if(divs[i].style.zIndex === 99999)
        {
            divs[i].style.display == "none";
        }
        if(divs[i].style.zIndex === "1000")
        {
            divs[i].style.display == "none";

        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    function damnwhitebox()
    {
     var myBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
     divs = myBody.getElementsByTagName("div");
        for(var i =0 ; i <divs.length; i++ )
        {
            if(divs[i].style.zIndex === 99999)
            {
                divs[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            if(divs[i].style.zIndex === 1000)
            {
                divs[i].style.display = "none";
                alert(divs[i].innerHTML);

            }
        }   
    }
```

This will work. As in your code you mixed syntax of for in and for loop. Use this one.

For ... in is meant to be used with objects to iterate over their properties. If you are going to use this with array, you have check you haven't added new properties to elements. So better is to avoid this syntax for array traversing.
And you should never use it on DOM array (like in this case) as many JavaScript library do extend DOM.

Comment: They didn't mix the syntax however using `for...in` will return more than just array indexes

Comment: This works because it is cycling through the indexed elements 0...N. If you use the `for (var i in divs)` loop, that will also try to iterate over divs.length (number) and divs.item (function)

Comment: divs[i].style.display == "none"; just evaluates the truthiness remove a "=" to make the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you probably want to change the == to =

```
divs[i].style.display = "none";
```